# SQL Programming

Tags: sql

I have this select sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `smth`,`smths`,`smthss` FROM sometbl WHERE `smt`='$smt' AND `smts`='$smts'";
```

How to substract the smth field from $smt ?

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you present a before and after overview of the data to give a better idea. Also, I take it you mean 'subtract' and not 'substitute'?

Comment: @NullUserException: You phrased that much more politely than I would have

Comment: WHERE `smt`='$smt - smth field' ,but in SQL ,without PHP (I know how to do it with PHP).Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT (smt-smth) as diff, smth, smths, smthss FROM sometbl WHERE smt='$smt' AND smts='$smts'";
```

Answer (score 1):

just subtract ($smt-smth)

```
SELECT  ($smt-smth) as differance, `smth`,`smths`,`smthss` FROM sometbl WHERE `smt`='$smt' AND `smts`='$smts'
```

Answer (score 0):

To subtract the `smth` field from `smt` in the `where` clause (as you indicate in one of the comments), use:

```
$sql = "SELECT `smth`,`smths`,`smthss` FROM sometbl WHERE `smt`='$smt' - `smth` AND `smts`='$smts'";
```

This will pass the:

```
 - `smth`
```

as-is through to the DBMS, not interpreted by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT ($smt - smth) as smth,`smths`,`smthss` FROM sometbl WHERE `smt`='$smt' AND `smts`='$smts'";
```